# Is there a limitation on business flow quantity in crm 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2016

I googled the question above and found an answer about **crm 2013** - it's possible to have up to 10 business flows per entity, I'm using **crm 2016** and current added 17 business flows to a single entity, I need to know if in **crm 2016** there is a limitation on business flow per entity and if there is how many can I create per Entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have 10+ Business process flows created per entity in CRM, but only of 10 (maximum) can be **activated** at any point of time. Other BPFs will be in **draft** mode.

> To ensure acceptable performance and the usability of the user
>   interface, there are some limitations you need to be aware of when you
>   plan to use business process flows:
>
> There can be no more than 10 activated business process flow processes
>   per entity.
>
> Each process can contain no more than 30 stages.
>
> Multi-entity processes can contain no more than five entities.
>
> Applies To
>   Dynamics 365 (online)
>   Dynamics 365 (on-premises)
>   Dynamics CRM Online
>   Dynamics CRM 2016
>   Dynamics CRM 2015
>   Dynamics CRM 2013

[Reference](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/business-process-flows-overview.aspx)

If you have more than 10 activated BPFs, Verify if someone in your team modified your CRM database entry (if it’s onprem) **MaximumActiveBusinessProcessFlowsAllowedPerEntity** in an [unsupported way](https://www.powerobjects.com/2015/09/02/two-tips-for-business-process-flows/).